# Having errors when importing Jquery to Angular 4

Tags: angular

I was trying to import bootstrap to my angular4 project. So first of all, I was trying to import jQuery.
I coded as showen below.

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

I am 100% percent sure I imported the js and css file.

And after that, I could do

```
$("asc").show()
```

However, when I do ng server. There appeared hundreds of errors about

console output:

```
"/Users/Eva/Desktop/auction/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts (6514,45): Duplicate identifier 'never'"
```

Anyone could tell what's could be the problem? I spent a lot of time and find a line of code in the `index.d.ts` of `@types/jQuery` saying:

`// TypeScript Version: 2.3` 
 and my `TypeScript version is 2.6`. Is this the problem? If it is, how to change to `2.3`? Any tsc after `2.3` couldn't use jQuery?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: Seems like that, because in ques `ng serve` is mentioned and angular-cli uses webpack

Comment: yes, you should rollback typescript: npm install typescript@2.3.4. fyi, to see all versions of a package: `npm show typescript versions --json`

Comment: Instead of rolling back just try to upgrade... `npm install @types/jquey@latest --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cli you can try these steps

```
This is without using typing in the below link you can find with types as well
```

Update your `Angular-cli.json`

```
  "scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
  ]
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var $ :any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

Then you can use the jquery in `ngAfterViewInit`

Working example in this [**link**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/TestingSPA/)

More on the same https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq